# Angular JS "Collapse" | Closed view by default

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an accordion and came across bootstrap's "Collapse".

```
collapse="isCollapsed"
```

When I load the page, the "Shared connections" panel is open by default, I'm wanting to have all panels "Shared connections" & "Other connections" closed by default until the user interacts with them.

Through my research so far, I haven't seen this done.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                      <div class="connections-wrap" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
                        <span class="connection-amount">3</span>
                        <span class="connection-type">Shared connections</span>
                        <i class="vf-i"></i>
                      </div>
                      <ul class="connections-list" collapse="isCollapsed">
                        <li>
                          <span class="connection-device">Eddie Benson Tablet</span>
                          <span class="connection-number">021 019 17338</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <span class="connection-device">Eddie Work Phone</span>
                          <span class="connection-number">021 019 17343</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <span class="connection-device">Eddie Work Android</span>
                          <span class="connection-number">021 019 17339</span>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="connections-wrap">
                        <span class="connection-amount">2</span>
                        <span class="connection-type">Other connections</span>
                        <i class="vf-i"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution - required ng-init="true" as collapse isn't being initialised on load.

```
ng-init="isCollapsed = true"
```